# MDB: wrong param binding in PDO query

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo, odbc

I have a code like these:

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM appsettings ORDER BY set_id DESC LIMIT 0,1";

$fetch = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$dbName = $row['set_mdb'];

if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={MDBTools}; DBQ=".realpath($dbName));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPTNAME NOT LIKE :honorer";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$keyword = "%HONORER%";
$colname = 'DEPTNAME';
$query->bindParam(':honorer', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$query->execute();
$query->debugDumpParams();

foreach ($query->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['DEPTID'].'">'.$row['DEPTNAME'].'</option>';
}
```

As you can see, I have an sql to run. If I only use this sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS";
```

It works normally. But when I try to use `where` or `order by` it return nothing. My DumpParam result is this:

```
SQL: [58] SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPTNAME NOT LIKE :honorer Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :honorer paramno=0 name=[8] ":honorer" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

Anyone know what cause this problem? I am new at PDO by the way. I'm looking at stackoverflow and php.net to see how to use PDO, because my database is .mdb (odbc) so I need to use this method.

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_` and `PDO` in the same script?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  he use two different databases (check second-one is`odbc`), but you are correct that he can do with same-one, either `mysqli_*` Or `PDO` but not both at the same time

Comment: Are you really accessing a MySQL database? Your connection string seems to indicate otherwise

Comment: does it works on php myadmin?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Because I have 2 database, one is mysql and other is mdb

Comment: @AlivetoDie at windows platform, it works smoothly... But when I change OS to linux, everything being error

Comment: @apokryfos I am using both mysql and mdb

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile sure not.. this is for ms access db (mdb). In ms access my query works... It's just I don't even know how to write query at PHP for PDO mdb..

Comment: Does MS Access support prepared statements? Would doing `$db->->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);` help?

Comment: @apokryfos It result Internal Server Error...

Comment: I put two `->->` there by accident, it should only be `->`

Comment: @apokryfos i have miss position. Your code does nothing... it result : `SQL: [58] SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPTNAME NOT LIKE :honorer Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :honorer paramno=0 name=[8] ":honorer" is_param=1 param_type=2`

Comment: Does the same query work in the database directly?

Comment: @apokryfos yes, if i do the query at ms access, it works fine.

Comment: Does it work without using a prepared statement in PHP?

Comment: @apokryfos nope, if i delete that prepare sql, it becomes error